# editing CMakeList.txt

Tags: ros, cmake, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was going through pr2_controller tutorials and came across the portion where we must build and run the program.
It says
make the binary by typing make in the drive_base_tutorial directory.
Where must I type this? In the CMakeList.txt file? and what does it mean by make the binary?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151176/editing-cmakelist.txt/) by [Ros_newbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/14601/ros_newbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It means exactly what it says.

In your terminal, run:

```
roscd drive_base_tutorial
make
```

`roscd drive_base_tutorial` will take you to the drive_base_tutorial directory (you can also use `cd` for this).

`make` is a build tool; it will call cmake, which will use the information in your CMakeLists.txt to call the compiler and the linker, converting your C++ code into an executable.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1